# Perl Not Writing to Buffer

Tags: perl, upload

For many years, I have used the following perl code I downloaded from a site to upload files to our linux server.  Basically, the user types a username and password into an html form, selects the file to upload, and clicks submit.  The script does the rest.  For some reason last week, the script stopped working.  I know it is opening the file to write to because I tried commenting out the 'unlink' line which would remove the file if nothing is written to it.  It does open the file for writing on the server, but when I open the file, there is nothing there.  I've tried changing file permissions and ownership on the directory where the uploaded files are stored without any results.  Any ideas or suggestions?  Thanks!

```
 my $DATA_DIR = '/Absolute/path/to/datadir/';   # Path of data directory
 my $DEFAULT_UPLOAD_DIR = '/tmp/'; #used only if you don't use password.

 my $MAX_SIZE_UPLOAD = 25; # Ko
 # File sizes are limited to $MAX_SIZE_UPLOAD (0 No limit), larger files will
 # return an 'Internal Server Error'.

 my $FORM_URL = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/upload.html';

 my $WEBMASTER_EMAIL = 'you@yourdomain.com';

 my $DISPLAY_LANG = 'En'; # Fr -> french

 my $USE_PASSWORD_PROTECT = 1; # 1 to use password protect 0 else.
 my $PASSWORD_FILE = $DATA_DIR.'password.txt'; # Name of Password file

 # En: Define all messages and buttons text.
 # Fr: Definition des messages et des boutons
 my(%NAME_BUTTON, %NAME_HEADTAB, %NAME_TITLE);

 if ($DISPLAY_LANG eq 'Fr') {
%NAME_BUTTON = ('exit' => 'Sortir', 'back' => 'Retour', 'add' => 'Ok', 
    'add_user' => 'Ajouter', 'edit_user' => 'Edit', 'del_user' => 'Supprimer',  'log' => 'Entrer');
 %NAME_HEADTAB = ('name' => 'Nom', 'level' => 'Droits', 'user_path' => 'R&eacute;pertoire utilisateur',
    'login' => 'Identifiant', 'password' => 'Mot de passe', 'new_login' => 'Nouvel identifiant',
    'new_pass' => 'Nouveau mot de passe', 'conf_pass' => 'Confimer mot de passe',
    'admin' => 'Administrateur', 'member' => 'Membre', 'w_path' => "(Chemin inexistant !)");
%NAME_TITLE   = ('common_admin' => "eUpload, &eacute;cran d'administration", 'common_member' => 'eUpload, &eacute;cran de chargement',
    'error_form' => 'Erreur : Formulaire incomplet', 'manage_users' => 'Management des utilisateurs', 'edit_user' => "Editer 'Value_login' utilisateur", 'add_user' => 'Ajout d\'un utilisateur',
    'user_saved' => "Utilisateur 'Value_login' sav&eacute;", 'user_added' => "Nouvel utilisateur 'Value_login' ajout&eacute;", 'user_deleted' => "Utilisateur 'Value_new_login' supprim&eacute;",
    'change_pass' => 'Changer votre mot de passe', 'chpass_invalid' => 'Nouveau mot de passe invalide', 'chpass_updated' => 'Mot de passe de Value_login mis &agrave; jour',
    'enter_pass' => 'Entrer votre mot de passe', 'invalid_pass' => 'MOT de PASSE INCORECT',
    'EU_BadFN' => "Error: Nom de fichier 'Value_FileName' incorrect", 'EU_FExist' => "Error: Fichier 'Value_FileName' existant, impossible de le modifier!",
    'EU_Size' => "Error: Erreur de chargement de 'Value_FileName'", 'Upload_Succes' => 'Chargement r&eacute;ussi !',
    'Upload_Succes_txt' => "'Value_FileName' (Value_Size bytes, Value_Time s) est sauv&eacute;");
 } else {
%NAME_BUTTON = ('exit' => 'Exit', 'back' => 'Back', 'add' => 'Ok', 
    'add_user' => 'Add', 'edit_user' => 'Edit', 'del_user' => 'Remove', 'log' => 'Log in');
%NAME_HEADTAB = ('name' => 'Name', 'level' => 'Level', 'user_path' => "User path",
    'login' => 'Login', 'password' => 'Password', 'new_login' => 'New Login',
    'new_pass' => 'New password', 'conf_pass' => 'Confim password',
    'admin' => 'Administrator', 'member' => 'Member', 'w_path' => "(Path don't exist !)");
%NAME_TITLE  = ('common_admin' => "eUpload, administrative display", 'common_member' => "eUpload, upload display",
    'error_form' => 'Error : Incomplet form', 'manage_users' => 'Manage Users', 'edit_user' => "Edit 'Value_login' user", 'add_user' => 'Add a user',
    'user_saved' => "User 'Value_login' saved", 'user_added' => "New user 'Value_login' added", 'user_deleted' => "User 'Value_new_login' deleted",
    'enter_pass' => 'Enter your password', 'invalid_pass' => 'INVALID PASSWORD',
    'EU_BadFN' => "Error: Bad Name 'Value_FileName'", 'EU_FExist' => "Error: File 'Value_FileName' exists, can not overwrite !",
    'EU_Size' => "Error: Could not upload file: 'Value_FileName'", 'Upload_Succes' => 'Upload uploaded successfully!',
    'Upload_Succes_txt' => "'Value_FileName' (Value_Size bytes, Value_Time s) was saved");
```

}

```
 use strict;
 use CGI;
 if ($MAX_SIZE_UPLOAD) { $CGI::POST_MAX=1024 * $MAX_SIZE_UPLOAD; } # Ko
 # File sizes are limited to 25K, larger files will return an 'Internal Server Error'

 my $query = new CGI;

 my $login    = $query->param('login');
 my $password = $query->param('pass');
 my $action   = $query->param('ac');

 my ($dir);

 if ($query->param('BT_Exit')) { $action = ''; }


 if ($action eq 'admin') {
print $query->header;
if ($login && $password)  {
    &admin($query, $login, $password);
} else {
    print &PagePassword($NAME_TITLE{'common_admin'});
}
 } elsif ($action eq 'upload') {
print $query->header;
if ($dir = &check_password('guest', $login, $password)) {
    print &Upload($query, $dir);
} else {
    print &BadPassword($NAME_TITLE{'common_member'});
}
 } else {
print $query->redirect($FORM_URL);
 }


sub Upload  {
my($query, $upload_dir) = @_;
my($file_query, $file_name, $size, $buff, $time, $bytes_count);
$size = $bytes_count =0;
$_ = $file_query = $query->param('file');
s/\w://;
s/([^\/\\]+)$//;
$_ = $1;
s/\.\.+//g;
s/\s+//g;
$file_name = $_;

if (! $file_name) {
    $_ = $NAME_TITLE{'EU_BadFN'};
    s/Value_FileName/$file_name/ig;
    &Error($_, 1);
}

if (-e "$upload_dir/$file_name") {
    $_ = $NAME_TITLE{'EU_FExist'};
    s/Value_FileName/$file_name/ig;
    &Error($_, 1);
}

open(FILE,">$upload_dir/$file_name") || &Error("Error opening file      $file_name for writing, error $!", 1);
binmode FILE;
$time=time();
while ($bytes_count = read($file_query,$buff,2096)) {
    $size += $bytes_count;
    print FILE $buff;
}
close(FILE);

if ((stat "$upload_dir/$file_name")[7] <= 0) {
    unlink("$upload_dir/$file_name");
    $_ = $NAME_TITLE{'EU_Size'};
    s/Value_FileName/$file_name/ig;
    &Error($_, 1);
} else {
    $time = time -$time;
    $_ = $NAME_TITLE{'Upload_Succes_txt'};
    s/Value_FileName/$file_name/ig;
    s/Value_Size/$size/ig;
    s/Value_Time/$time/ig;
    &ResutPage($NAME_TITLE{'Upload_Succes'}, $_);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can it be that your `$file_query` is just empty?  Check the (final) `$size` that you build while writing?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I did try this, and it is showing 0 for the size.  However, prior to that happening, I tried the upload again, and it worked twice.  Then, it stopped working again.  It is very strange.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That would mean that the problem is outside of this routine, no? The `$query` used to get `$file_query` is passed in and we don't know what's on that handle anyway.

Comment: OK, I tried to edit and paste in all of the code prior to the upload subscript.  So far, I have not been able to get the upload to work again.

Comment: Just FYI, the variable values have been changed on the working version.  What you see here are the default variables from the original script I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears clear that the problem lies with the file being uploaded, outside of (before) the shown code.  The code prints to `$file_name` obtained by cleaning up `$file_query`, which is pulled from `$query`. This is the CGI object itself that is passed into the sub. I cannot see anything in the code that would mess with the data to be used to write the `$file_name`.

This would imply that the data for which `$file_query` is a filehandle is (sometimes) missing, so when you copy it via your `read()` loop to `$file_name` you get nothing.

The one thing I can recommend is to test for the size of the (temp) file that is being copied into `$file_name`. **See Update below for how to do that.** Any other diagnostics would have to happen elsewhere, so it seems.

Another (distant?) possibility is that the filehandle pulled from `$query` has been used to read (or write) and does not any more point to the beginning of the file -- but rather to the end.  This would also not be in the shown code.  **Update:** it may be worth trying `seek $query_file, 0, 0` before the `read` loop, to 'rewind` to the beginning of the file.

The code can be improved but I don't see how any of it can cause this problem.

---

**Update**

The script reads via `read($file_query, ...)`, where `$file_query` is set earlier by

```
$_ = $file_query = $query->param('file')
```

The `query->param` returns names of things, while [`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) needs a filehandle.  By CGI's convenience what is returned by `param` *can* be used as a filehandle as well. However, a filehandle is properly obtained from the CGI object by the method `$query->upload('file')`.

Then it would be worth trying to get the filehandle via `upload` method and use that in the `read` loop, instead of `$file_query`.  See [File upload](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-4.28/lib/CGI.pod#Processing_a_file_upload_field) section in [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-4.28/lib/CGI.pod) docs.

---

**Update**

From  [File upload](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-4.28/lib/CGI.pod#Processing_a_file_upload_field) in CGI.pm docs

> When processing an uploaded file, CGI.pm creates a temporary file on your hard disk and passes you a file handle to that file.

Check *this* file to see whether the file made it to the server at all. Do this before the `upload()` sub. The linked docs give us

```
my $fh_tmp  = $query->upload( 'file' );
my $tmpfilename = $query->tmpFileName( $fh_tmp );
```

Now `$tmpfilename` can be queried for size, for example by the same `stat` your code uses to check the `$file_name` size, or simply using Perl's [file-test operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

```
(if -z $tmpfilename)  { print "Empty file (exists but zero size)!\n" }
```

If *that* file is zero-size you know that the problem is earlier.

Comment: OK.  Well, thank you for your help and for looking at it.  I'll just keep working with it to see what I can do.

Comment: @user1681502  I've added and reworded text, a thing or two to try, and one **specific diagnostic step** that has to yield some insight into where the problem is.  Please see **Update** places.  Please let me know what you find out.

Comment: Sorry to take so long on a response, but I was finally able to try your suggestion of checking the temporary file, and it seems to be empty as well.  Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: @user1681502  Thank you very much for the attribution. I'll have to read up a little on _all_ that happens with a CGI scipt, since that file just isn't making it up there and I can't think of what part could be failing now.  Were there any changes in the system that you know about? With servers? With the OS? With rules? I don't see anything wrong with the code, and you (later) posted yet another version of it, which also looks fine. So I'd look elsewhere in the process.

Comment: @user1681502  Something just came up, so let me pass it on to you.  1) What is the userid? If it's  `web` or `nobody` write-permissions are restricted, with good reasons. Then you can create a world-writable file in `/tmp` or so. Or, you can configure the server to run with your userid, then it can write in your space. (2) Permissions, on files and directories, are they what they should be and do they agree with each other. (3) A wild guess -- SELinux settings?  Some of these may not apply but I can't check now, please consider.  ...  oh, no you _can_ create_ a file. Still worth checking?